# Is there any way to simplify the bitwise operation?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am studying about bitwise logical operations.(OR,AND,XOR....etc)
And I want to know how to simplify the bitwise operation
For example:
I want to Set A, Clear B, Toggle C, in the same time.
if Input is 0100, and output is 1010

if there is any way to perform this bitwise operation?
Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot do more than one of set/clear/toggle in a single operation. But you can do the same operation across multiple bits (bitwise operations are effectively just a primitive form of SIMD).

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Show your attempt. If you google, there are quite a good tutorials available .

Comment: I suppose it is *mathematically* possible to do different kinds of operations at once by creating a bit matrix and then applying it, but this will involve a *lot* of individual operations, so it's unlikely this will be beneficial unless you're doing something really fancy and have the math to prove it correct. (I've done this to advance an LFSR by an arbitrary amount)

Comment: If you want the complete result to take effect on the target variable or hardware register in one operation, use a temporary variable and operate on it.

Answer (score 1):

- Setting is done using OR or NAND<sup>[1][2]</sup>.
- Clearing is done using AND<sup>[2]</sup> or NOR<sup>[1]</sup>.
- Toggling is done using XOR<sup>[3]</sup> or XNOR<sup>[4]</sup>.

There is no overlap; these are different operations and thus would have to be done separately.

You can perform the same operation on multiple bits at once, but not different operations on different bits.

---

1. Requires a negated input.
2. Requires a negated mask.
3. Neither the input nor the mask must be negated, or both must be.
4. Requires a negated input or a negated mask, but not both.

Comment: oops, didn't see your answer...

Comment: Actually XOR can do all those operations simultaneously if you give it the correct input - 0 where the input is the same as the result, and 1 where they are opposite.  But generating that value is more work than just doing the 3 operations separately.

Comment: @MarkRansom Using a sequence of operations that ends with a XOR operation is not using a XOR operation. By your logic, a NOT operation would do all those operations simultaneously, seeing as a XOR operation can be composed of AND and NOT operations that ends with a NOT operation.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework so i'll refrain from using your example or giving code but IMHO the cleanest way is probably to to write SET as OR with a number that has ones in the desired positions, bet way to CLEAR is probably to and with a number that has zeros at the desired positions and for toggle you guessed it xor at the desired position this is because anything OR 1 is always 1, anything and 0 is always 0 and something xor 1 is always the inverse of that thing.

usually the compiler can optimize the operations so it's not a real problem on that front

as for an example let's take an 8 bit number

11110000 and set the first and 5th bits, clear the second and 6th bits and toggle the 3rd and 7th bits.

11110000 | 10001000 = 11111000

11111000 & 10111011 = 10111000

10111000 ^(xor) 00100010 = 10011010